# How to find which function prints printk statement?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, printk

Is it a way to find in which function `printk` was executed?
I know that I can add `__function__` to my `printk` to get this information, but I'm working with big project and it's kinda impossible to add this to all `printk` manually.

Maybe I should add some macros to code or use some linux command?

Comment: Easiest way is to use Dynamic Debug functionality along with `pr_debug()`, `dev_dbg()` and so on. Dynamic Debug allows you to switch function printing at run time. For the rest flavors of `pr_*()` macros, it usually doesn’t make sense since we are talking about in-kernel programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we are talking about Linux kernel programming, there are several ways to achieve this. The worst one is to define custom macro where you add something additional to print. Now, let's consider better approaches.

**Approach 1.**
If you are interesting to put function name to only subset of the messages, assuming for debug purposes, the best option is to enable [Dynamic Debug](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/dynamic-debug-howto.html) option and use special macros instead of direct calls to `printk`, i.e. `pr_debug()`, `dev_dbg()`, `netdev_dbg()` and so on.

It will allow you to turn on and off any single message at run time along with enabling *__func__* to be printed or not.

**Approach 2.**
Another approach if you want to enable additional arguments to the families of macros, such as `pr_*()` and `dev_*()`, you may define special macros at the very beginning of each module or, if you want, include from the header, though it must be the very fist one in each C-file. See example from [ipmi_msghandler.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/char/ipmi/ipmi_msghandler.c#L15):

```
#define pr_fmt(fmt) "%s" fmt, "IPMI message handler: "
#define dev_fmt pr_fmt
```

It can be easily transformed to

```
#define pr_fmt(fmt) "%s(): " fmt, __func__
#define dev_fmt pr_fmt
```

The benefit of this method is a possibility to set up different prefixes to different modules, like using their filenames, and it will be applied to all messages of the same family of macros.

Disadvantage is that only `pr_*()` and `dev_*()` families do have such facilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some macro (at least with `printf`, but the principle is the same with `printk`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* redefine printf for the rest of file. */
#define printf(...) \ 
do { \
    printf("%s: %d:\t", __FILE__, __LINE__);\    
    printf(__VA_ARGS__);\
} while (0)

/* after this point, each call to printf will be replaced by two. */


int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Will print (tested from https://tio.run/#c-gcc):

```
.code.tio.c: 12:    Hello
```

Instead of just

```
Hello
```

Comment: It’s about Linux kernel where additional instruments are present.

Comment: using two `printf()` thinking they will be merged is a huge mistake and doesn't work anymore